# Integral of $x^n y^m$ on the unit disc

Tags: integration, change-of-variable

Let $E = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2+y^2 \leq 1 \}$. Compute $$ \int_E x^n y^m \ dx \ dy$$ for all $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$.

What is the best way to do this? One can, of course, transform it using polar coordinates which leaves some trigonometric integral that can be solved with integration by parts and trigonometric formulas.

That approach seems rather nasty, though. Is there a nicer way?

Comment: By the way, if $m$ or $n$ is odd, the integral will be zero (why?). So you only really need to worry about the case where $m$ and $n$ are both even.

Comment: The usual double integral with cartesian coordinates doesn't look so bad, either. Anyway, there doesn't seem to be a much better way than cartesian or polar coordinates.

Comment: May I ask how to do compute it with cartesian coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in many ways, as the resulting [beta-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) has many equivalent representations.

As already was noted in the comments we can assume both $n\mapsto2n$ and $m\mapsto2m$ to be even and restrict the integration domain to the first quadrant.

For example:
$$\begin{array}{}
\frac I4&=\int\limits_0^1x^{2n}dx\int\limits_0^\sqrt{1-x^2}y^{2m}dy
=\frac{1}{2m+1}\int\limits_0^1 x^{2n}(1-x^2)^{m+\frac12}dx\\
&\stackrel{x^2\mapsto t}=\frac{1}{2(2m+1)}\int\limits_0^1 t^{n-\frac12}(1-t)^{m+\frac12}dt=\frac{B(n+\frac12,m+\frac32)}{2(2m+1)},
\end{array}
$$
or:
$$\begin{array}{}
\frac I4&=\int\limits_0^1 r^{2n+2m+1}dr\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n}\phi\sin^{2m}\phi\;d\phi
=\frac{B(n+\frac12,m+\frac12)}{4(n+m+1)}.
\end{array}
$$

The results seemingly differ but in fact they are the same due to:
$$
B(x,y+1)=B(x,y)\frac{y}{x+y},
$$
and can be expressed in terms of more "elementary" functions as:
$$\begin{array}{}
I(n,m)=\frac{B(n+\frac12,m+\frac12)}{n+m+1}
=\frac1{n+m+1}\frac{\Gamma(n+\frac12)\Gamma(m+\frac12)}{\Gamma(n+m+1)}
=\frac{(2n-1)!!(2m-1)!!}{2^{n+m}(n+m+1)!}\pi.\end{array}
$$

Comment: Beta function almost seems like a bit of an overkill but it‘s very nice, of course! Thank you!